# Looking for a proxy device

Tags: networking

My cousin has internet at home and he did agree to give me a proxy for browsing internet. He can use a proxy server program (like CCProxy or AnalogX) on his Windows PC but I wonder if there is any device that can connect to the router using Ethernet cable and to provide me a proxy. It should be a small device and cheap and it should use little electricity, just like a router or a switching hub.

Is there any such product available to buy from providers like D-Link or Netgear, is anyone producing such a device?

Comment: Depending on your Router, or if you can can get a spare/second hand... you _might_ be able to reflash it with OpenWrt or similar, which has several Proxy server options (Privoxy being one). Check their website OpenWrt.org for compatible hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using a Raspberry PI? They are small, cheap and generally low on power consumption so that might meet your needs. I have not tried this but it looks like [someone has made a tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/683971/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-proxy-server-with-privoxy/#:%7E:text=Scroll%20to%20the%20%E2%80%9CNetwork%20Settings,and%20then%20click%20%E2%80%9CSettings.%E2%80%9D&text=Under%20%E2%80%9CConfigure%20Proxy%20Access%20to,in%20the%20%E2%80%9CPort%E2%80%9D%20field.) on setting one up.